# How to store 15 x 100 million 32-byte records for sequential access?

Tags: sql, database, nosql

Me got 15 x 100 million 32-byte records. Only sequential access and appends needed. The key is a Long. The value is a tuple - (Date, Double, Double). Is there something in this universe which can do this? I am willing to have 15 seperate databases (sql/nosql) or files for each of those 100 million records. I only have a i7 core and 8 GB RAM and 2 TB hard disk.

I have tried PostgreSQL, MySQL, Kyoto Cabinet (with fine tuning) with Protostuff encoding.

SQL DBs (with indices) take forever to do the silliest query.

Kyoto Cabinet's B-Tree can handle upto 15-18 million records beyond which appends take forever.

I am fed up so much that I am thinking of falling back on awk + CSV which I remember used to work for this type of data.

Comment: Not sure if it's just me misunderstanding, but I'm not sure I understand why you'd need a key if you say you only do sequential access...?

Comment: A database should be able to handle that much better than awk'ing a CSV file....  Something is wrong with your schema.

Comment: "Something is wrong with your schema" - probably more likely due to having a single 'non-enterprise' hard disk instead of appropriate RAID arrays and file placements

Comment: What size is a `long`in this case? 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson The keys are for duplicate values, and to know they are different. I could put the key inside the value, but I just want say it is there. I think it is good practice to have primary key in SQL DBs and keys in NoSQL DBs.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson the long is 64 bit.

It seems you are keen on finding contradictions in my post. Not to worry, this problem is real and I am not faking it.

Comment: What are some of the queries you want to be able to do efficiently?  I find it odd that you're finding the databases that you've tried inadequate.

Comment: @DavidWallace I want to select everything in order of date. Move back and forth sequentially through the results.

Comment: So, have an index by date; and write queries that have results within a specific date range.  Page back and forth by re-issuing the query when you get to the start or the end of the set of results that you've got.  Do NOT try to fetch everything at once with a single query - that's not what SQL is for.

Comment: @louzer Not hunting contradictions, had the key been 32 bit and actually used for lookups, a 128GB flat file would have solved your problem with just `seek(key*32); read(32 bytes);`.

Answer (score 2):

If you scenario means *always* going through all records in sequence then it may be an overkill to use a database. If you start to need random lookups, replacing/deleting records or checking if a new record is not a duplicate of an older one, a database engine would make more sense.

For the sequential access, a couple of text files or hand-crafted binary files will be easier to handle. You sound like a developer - I would probably go for an own binary format and access it with help of memory-mapped files to improve the sequential read/append speed. No caching, just a sliding window to read the data. I think that it would perform better and even on usual hardware than any DB would; I did such data analysis once. It would also be faster than awking CSV files; however, I am not sure how much and if it satisfied the effort to develop the binary storage, first of all.

As soon as the database becomes interesting, you can have a look at [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) and [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/). They are used for storing and serving *very* large amounts of data. (There is a [flattering evaluation](http://perfectmarket.com/blog/not_only_nosql_review_solution_evaluation_guide_chart) that compares one of them to traditional DBs.). Databases usually need a reasonable hardware power to perform better; maybe you could check out how those two would do with your data.

--- Ferda

Answer (score 1):

Ferdinand Prantl's answer is very good. Two points:

- By your requirements I recommend that you create a very tight binary format. This will be easy to do because your records are fixed size.
- If you understand your data well you might be able to compress it. For example, if your key is an increasing log value you don't need to store it entirely. Instead, store the difference to the previous value (which is almost always going to be one). Then, use a standard compression algorithm/library to save on data size big time.

Answer (score 1):

For sequential reads and writes, leveldb will handle your dataset pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's about 48 gigs of data in one table.

When you get into large databases, you have to look at things a little differently. With an ordinary database (say, tables less than a couple million rows), you can do just about anything as a proof of concept.  Even if you're stone ignorant about SQL databases, server tuning, and hardware tuning, the answer you come up with will probably be right. (Although sometimes you might be right for the wrong reason.)

That's not usually the case for large databases.

Unfortunately, you can't just throw 1.5 billion rows straight at an untuned PostgreSQL server, run a couple of queries, and say, "PostgreSQL can't handle this."  Most SQL dbms have ways of dealing with lots of data, and most people don't know that much about them.

Here are some of the things that I have to think about when I have to process a lot of data over the long term. (Short-term or one-off processing, it's usually not worth caring a lot about speed. A lot of companies won't invest in more RAM or a dozen high-speed disks--or even a couple of SSDs--for even a long-term solution, let alone a one-time job.)

- Server CPU.
- Server RAM.
- Server disks.
- RAID configuration. (RAID 3 might be worth looking at for you.)
- Choice of operating system. (64-bit vs 32-bit, BSD v. AT&T derivatives)
- Choice of DBMS. (Oracle will usually outperform PostgreSQL, but it costs.)
- DBMS tuning. (Shared buffers, sort memory, cache size, etc.)
- Choice of index and clustering. (Lots of different kinds nowadays.)
- Normalization. (You'd be surprised how often 5NF outperforms lower NFs. Ditto for natural keys.)
- Tablespaces. (Maybe putting an index on its own SSD.)
- Partitioning.

I'm sure there are others, but I haven't had coffee yet.

But the point is that you can't determine whether, say, PostgreSQL can handle a 48 gig table unless you've accounted for the effect of all those optimizations.  With large databases, you come to rely on the cumulative effect of small improvements.  You have to do a lot of testing before you can defensibly conclude that a given dbms can't handle a 48 gig table.

Now, whether you can *implement* those optimizations is a different question--most companies won't invest in a new 64-bit server running Oracle and a dozen of the newest "I'm the fastest hard disk" hard drives to solve your problem.

But someone *is* going to pay either for optimal hardware and software, for dba tuning expertise, or for programmer time and waiting on suboptimal hardware. I've seen problems like this take months to solve. If it's going to take months, money on hardware is probably a wise investment.